# Can't seem to find unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

For a college project I'm developing an app with Django Framework that allows users to find restaurants and other venues near them, and obtain a route to them through the Google Directions Service.

I just copied the `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function from the service overview code sample into my template, and I keep getting an unexpected identifier error, but I don't see the problem.

Keep in mind that I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I might be overlooking something obvious here. Here's the code snippet:

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: new.google.maps.LatLng(43.0186, -7.5813),
      destination: new.google.maps.LatLng(43.0157, -7.5495),
      travelMode: travel_mode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm getting the error on the 'origin: ...' line. Origin and destination values are fixed for testing purposes. Here's the complete script: https://pastebin.com/sbNtVLYk

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: full template code: https://pastebin.com/8rhTGPXA

Comment: Throw the code in the editor on jsfiddle.com and let the linter tell you the problems with your code.

Comment: Can you link the "service overview" code you copied?  Does this typo exist in the official documentation?

Comment: My bad, it's not in the service overview page. Here's the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple. The typo does not exist there. Removing 'new' from the line solved that issue, but now I'm getting the same error on the first line of the template when I trigger the function

Comment: @EnriqueGarcíaRodríguez Can you update the code in your question to match your latest revision?

Comment: I just updated the post with the full template. The button that triggers the function is added to each infoWindow through the contentString variable. I assume I must be doing something wrong about this.

Comment: I haven't had the time to do some tests, though

Comment: I have identified the issue. If I use string concatenation to add directionsService and directionsDisplay as parameters to the function (inside the contentString variable, onclick event), they're casted to String.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a reserved work in JavaScript, see a description here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

So the invalid lines are

```
  origin: new.google.maps.LatLng(43.0186, -7.5813),
  destination: new.google.maps.LatLng(43.0157, -7.5495),
```

This is also being highlighted by the code highlighting here on stackoverflow.

Comment: That should be closed as a typo. How will this ever be helpful for anyone else?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized it was being highlighted by stackoverflow's code highlighting. Though now I'm getting the same error on the first line of the template when I click the button in the infoWindow. Here's the full template: https://pastebin.com/8rhTGPXA